# Why doesn't my packet beat work as I thought it would？

Tags: packetbeat

I set the configuration file for PacketBeat to only collect network traffic for the NFS protocol.However, when I looked at the collected data, I did not find any events containing "type: nfs". The collected data is all "type: flow". What is the reason for this?

```
packetbeat.protocols:
- type: nfs
  ports: [2049]
```

I want to know how to use packet beat to collect network traffic information between the local machine and NAS.